# Word(s) meaning "to understand deeply"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm looking for a word meaning "to understand deeply".

*Profound* is the word I want to express. However, *profound* can only be used as an adjective. I'm looking for a verb form.

Example:

> Susan _____ her sister's troubles.

Comment: Is this understanding a person or a concept? If you understand a concept, a good verb may be "comprehend."

Comment: Can you add a sample sentence to your question with a blank where the word should be?

Comment: *Profound* just means *deep*.

Answer (score 11):

## *grok*

The word that comes to mind is *grok*.  This term originally comes from Robert Heinlein’s 1961 science-fiction novel [*A Stranger in a Strange Land*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land#Grok), but it has since entered the popular culture, and Merriam-Webster defines it as “to understand profoundly and intuitively”.

Comment: +1 because it perfectly matches in the communities it's known in, though it's definitely a slang sense and not much used outside of some tech, sci-fi, US Pagan and GB comic-book fandom communities (the first three pretty directly from Heinlein, the comic-book fans as much from Judge Dredd as from the original source).

Comment: @JonHanna Here’s [a citation for *grok*](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/grok.html) from Eric S. Raymond’s *New Hacker’s Dictionary* (né the Jargon File). This shows how hackers use it, or at least, how the hacker community were using it more than two decades ago now when ESR wrote that entry, which was long before the 1996 publication of that tome.

Comment: While I'm the first to appreciate slang, and geeky terms, I feel duty bound  to warn nonnative speakers that this does not fit the OP's example sentence. `Susan grokked her sister's problem` is  wholly inappropriate, and should never be used in a formal context.

Comment: @tchrist the jargon file as of the time Guy Steele et al. published it as "The Hackers' Dictionary" (though it of course existed as a live document in MIT-AI for a long time before that) had just: "GROK [from the novel 'Stranger in a Strange Land', by Robert Heinlein, where it is a Martian word meaning roughly "to be one with"] v. To understand, usually in a global sense.", so as a jargon file entry it precedes ESR though he added to it.

Answer (score 5):

To ***[grasp](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grasp)***.

> Comprehend fully:
> *‘the press failed to grasp the significance of what had happened’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grasp

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a metaphor of depth:

> Sally had fathomed the plot.
>
> The professor had spent twenty years penetrating the arcana of Phoenician religion.
>
> We got to the bottom of it.

Metaphors for 'absorbing' or 'eating' could work, too:

> I absorbed the course material.
>
> Wendy has assimilated the entire book.
>
> He digested the pamphlet.
>
> They took it all in.

Comment: `Grok`, also given as an answer here is an example of the latter, since in the source story it's literal meaning is "drink".

Answer (score 2):

If it is a concept that is being understood, then [comprehend](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprehend) may work.

> to grasp the nature, significance, or meaning of. Ex: "unable to comprehend what has happened"

Usage: "After years of study, he managed to comprehend quantum physics. His wife, not so much."

Answer (score 0):

How about **fathom** or **assimilate**?

OD:

> [**fathom**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fathom):
>   Understand (a difficult problem or an enigmatic person) after much
>   thought
>
> [**assimilate**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assimilate):
>   Take in and understand fully (information or ideas)

Answer (score 0):

A word which neatly fits in the example sentence is ***appreciate***.

> Susan ***appreciates*** her sister's troubles.

ODO:

> **[appreciate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appreciate)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> **2** Understand (a situation) fully; grasp the full implications of:
>   ‘they failed to appreciate the pressure he was under’

Answer (score 0):

I found out the word I was looking for. The ward was "contemplate"!!!

Comment: You've self answered a question with a word that in no way fits the sense of the question as asked. Please be more careful in future to ask what you mean to ask. We also ask you when answering, to provide an authoritative reference and definition to single word requests.

Answer (score 0):

While the above answers must satisfy your need (alongwith the list of [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/apprehend) ) on a slightly different note (as a suggestion) consider [***imbibe***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imbibe) also.

> 2 a:   to receive into the mind and 
>   retain  
>   b :   to assimilate or take into 
>   solution

***Susan imbibes her sister's troubles.***
 

 Also from Wikitionary:

> 2. (figuratively) To take in; absorb to imbibe knowledge

**Oxford Dictionary:**

> Absorb or assimilate (ideas or knowledge)
>   **Dictionary.com:**
>   to take or receive into the mind, as
>    knowledge, ideas, or the like: 
>   -to imbibe a sermon; 
>   -to imbibe
>    beautiful scenery.

I think if one 'absorbs or assimilates the idea' they must also '**deeply understand it.**' Just thought you might want to consider.